# How Spark shuffle operation works?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm learning Spark for my project and I'm in stuck with shuffle process in Spark. I want to know how this operation works internal. I found some keywords involved in this operation: ShuffleMapStage, ShuffleMapTask, ShuffledRDD, Shuffle Write, Shuffle Read....

My questions are:

1. Why we need ShuffleMapStage? When this stage is created and how it works?
2. When ShuffledRDD's compute method is called?
3. What are Shuffle Read and Shuffle Write?

Answer (score 1):

The [suffle operation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations) consist to distribute coherent data on workers (repartition) using hash function on data key (data localilty problem).

This operation involves data transfert to organise data before perform an action, reduce the number of suffle operation increase the performance.

Shuffle operation are automatically called by Spark between 2 [transformation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations) to execute a final [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions).

Some Spark transformation need shuffle (like Group by, Join, sort)

Some Spark transformation doesn't need shuffle (like Union, Map, Reduce, Filter, count)